# Edit to remove Answer from Question rejected

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

Came across to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14013999/6195472) question. And saw the OP edited the question when a solution was found to the question. At that time the question looked like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14013999/3).
So I grabbed the answer from the question and pasted it as a community wiki answer. Then I edited the main question to remove the answer. But my suggested edit was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19821650). *(after some time one of the users that accepted my edit, edited the question like what I did)*

Did I do something wrong and is this something not to do? Or it was supposed to be accepted?
What does "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer." even mean?

Edit: It's not the first time that this OP has edited the question to include the answer. [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14029542/revisions), [#3](https://askubuntu.com/posts/272796/revisions)

Comment: I edited the other question to remove the answer (don't need to be reviewed). Thanks for adding the answer there.

Comment: this is where the *crowd* gets in a wrong on a regular basis. The review queue *crowd* is much less informed than the general population. **You did the correct thing**, and even left an informative and correct message why you did what you did. They robo-reviewed, that is all.

Comment: Unfortunately the edit review queue is a massive failure. Might as well just flip a coin to see if your edit is approved or not.

Comment: Hopefully some diamond comes along and hands out some review bans...

Comment: The important part is to write a detailed edit reason to explain the reason for removal, as the edit reviewers may otherwise not see the full picture. But you did this, so it's a bit surprising that this got rejected. I peeked at the users who rejected and while none of them have very high rep, they were all fairly experienced reviewers (all had 1k reviews or more). Bad reviewing usually goes the other way: accepting edits that shouldn't be accepted. So I guess this was just bad luck, 3 reviewers doing a mistake at the same time.

Comment: Anyway, these kind of issues are often best solved by someone with edit privileges who can simply rollback the question into a previous revision.

Comment: @Lundin "The important part is to write a detailed edit reason to explain the reason for removal" nope, that doesn't work. [It hasn't worked since years yonce](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199584/213575).

Comment: As @Lundin pointed out, proper action is rollback. Posting wiki answer and *editing* the answer are wrong. For you (without rollback permission, which require 2k+ I think) just post a comment.

Comment: @Sinatr but then where would the answer go? There was a valid (and working) answer on that question. If someone rolled it back to before that edit, then the answer was lost. Where would it go? You can't post it as the OP..

Comment: Usually this types of answers are poor, nothing more than copy/pasted block of code from the beginner. Usually there are already comments or even answers telling what to do, so you do not really need that answer from OP. There is rollback history, so creating answer anytime later is not a problem. And there are always exceptions from the rule, so it may come eventually to you posting wiki answer to preserve that valuable info to future visitors.. who knows? Main point - do not start with doing it, you are simply stealing potential reward from OP..

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The edit should (imho) have been accepted. Removing answers from questions is something that should definitely be done.

Answer (score 29):

I have an *auto comment* that I put on edits like these.

> Answers go in an **Answer** box not as edits to the question. You can
>   then **Accept** your own answer as the solution by clicking the Arrow
>   to make it green. Do not edit the title to say `[SOLVED]` either. This is not a forum, do not treat it like one.

I usually do not put the answer in an answer box because I want to give the OP the ability to do it and possibly get credit for it from future visitors.

That said, what you did with the community wiki answer is acceptable just as well especially if you have no reason to think they are going to do it themselves. (Like on an 8 year old question or their *"last seen date"* is years ago.)

Comment: This is exactly what I do in these situation (well, the text is a bit different...) Never thought about adding a community wiki answer or even remove the answer from the question. I leave that to the OP.

Comment: Fair point. However, FYI, the [consensus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117251/164088) seems to be that answers in comments should be reposted on sight as proper answers (with full attribution), rather than letting them fester. The same logic applies to answers in questions. Concern for site quality should take precedence over allocation of reputation points.